# How to make 'style' with value '?attr/actionButtonStyle

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

[/storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/data/743/files/resource/layout/custom_action_item_layout.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?attr/actionButtonStyle')., , /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/data/743/files/resource/menu/main_menu.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionLayout' in package 'com.my.newproject9', , /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/data/743/files/resource/menu/main_menu.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.my.newproject9', ]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have referenced the attr `actionButtonStyle` from somewhere and this attribute is not set in your App theme.

Assuming that you are using material themes for your app, at first, create a theme for your buttons. Following is an example and you can customize it as you need:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
</style>
```

Now, in your app theme, set this attribute value to the new theme:

```
<!--Your app theme might be different than the following, just put that attribute inside-->
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
</style>
```

Hope, this helps.